# How to remove %SystemDrive% from project folder?

Tags: python

While I was using Atom, I received an error saying that I needed to run this command: `python -m pip install 'python-language-server[all]'`. After what seemed to be a successful install using PowerShell, I now see a %SystemDrive% folder in all of my Python project folders. This wasn't there previously and has become quite an annoyance. I'm not new to coding, but am pretty new to Python. Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Expanded %SystemDrive% in Python project]

Comment: What is the %SystemDrive% folder being used for in your project? Why is it quite an annoyance?

Comment: I have no clue what it's for... I'm assuming cache of some sort but no idea for what. It's an annoyance because whenever I try to push to GitHub, it marks it as a change but I don't want to commit it. I've been manually selecting the changes I want since I can't seem to discard the %SystemDrive% changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pip has anything to do with this. All the pip installs are generally stored in the python's parent directory. By default i.e. `C:\Python\` I am pretty sure that is some cache of an OS. So feel free to remove it.

But next time let's have a legit better question. This is not fun, people tend to look genuine answers here, respect this community.